# Plotly Express in Spyder IDE

Tags: plotly, spyder, plotly-express

How can i use Ploty Express in Spyder IDE?

I have tried the suggestion from this [link](https://community.plotly.com/t/plotly-express-in-spyder-offline-instead-of-iplot/21743). But i couldn't make it work. It is not even opening my default web browser (Google Chrome). Instead, it opens Internet Explorer in the main page.

I am trying something like this:

```
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.offline import plot    
fig = px.density_mapbox(...)
plot(fig)
```

**EDIT:** Actually, a html file is being created in my working directory with the plot. So i must add something to my question.

Why is it opening Internet Explorer in the main page? Instead of just opening a new Chrome or new Tab in my already opened Chrome with the plot in it?1

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to configure which browser gets used.

Comment: @MadPhysicist i tried force the renderer as `pio.renderers.default = "chrome"` but nothing changed (i.e, it still opens Internet Explorer in the main page and creates a html file with the plot in my working directory).

Comment: Maybe you need to set Chrome as the default program to open `.html` files?

Comment: @DanielAlthviz It was already my default program for that.

Comment: I checked with some example code and the plot gets opened in my default browser (Firefox). Quite strange that in your setup is not working as expected and no idea what could be happening :/